# Changing the order of a GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql

With this query I get a set of data

```
SELECT UID, CouncilNam, Probabilit, Scored_Lab, PTC_ID
FROM london.london
```

I want to group by PTC_ID and Scored_Lab which I can do with this...

```
SELECT UID, CouncilNam, Probabilit, Scored_Lab, PTC_ID
FROM london.london
GROUP BY PTC_ID, Scored_Lab
```

However, in the initial query there are multiple rows with grouped Scored_Lab and PTC_ID but differing Probability values. I want the lowest from this set but the default selection within group by doesn't provide this.

I have read dozens of similar queries on here but still cannot work it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just do  `min(Probabilit)`?

Comment: *"I want the lowest from this set but the default selection within group by doesn't provide this."* -- there is "no default selection within group". Your query is not valid SQL. You can use [`MIN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) to get the lowest value for each column but if you want to get the entire row that contains the minimum then you are on the wrong path; `GROUP BY` cannot do that.

Comment: Your Select statement is invalid SQL - you can not select columns that are not part of the grouping. MySQL will _tolerate_ this error when configured to do so - but you will get a value from a _random_ record in the group for those columns. _“I want the lowest from this set”_ - then simply apply https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I think I may have solved it using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you are looking for something along these lines:

```
SELECT
    PTC_UD,
    Scored_Lab,
    MIN(Probabilit)    -- take the smallest probability in each group
FROM london.london
GROUP BY PTC_ID, Scored_Lab
```

Note that selecting the `UID` and `CouncilNam` columns may not be valid, or may not make sense, because you did not specify them as aggregates of the groups in your query.

Here is a general query you can use to get full matching rows for each probability minimum group:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM london.london t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PTC_UD, Scored_Lab, MIN(Probabilit) AS p_min
    FROM london.london
    GROUP BY PTC_ID, Scored_Lab
) t2
    ON t1.PTC_UD     = t2.PTC_UD     AND
       t1.Scored_Lab = t2.Scored_Lab AND
       t1.Probabilit = t2.p_min
```